# In javascript Repeating property in the object definition (within the curly brackets). is it an error ?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if the following javascript is 'valid' or not.

```
var object = {
   'name' : 'test',
   'age' : 56,
   'age' : 25
}
```

As you can see I deliberately repeated one of the attributes. (age)

For what it matters
A quick test on chrome seems to prove that the javascript is valid and object.age is equal to 25.

p.s. 
I am asking this because we have written some javascript code generator and I want to know if that is valid js or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically it *is* valid, but *not* recommended.

According to [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (emphasis mine):

> 2.2.  Objects
>   An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
>      surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
>      string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
>      from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
>      name.  **The names within an object SHOULD be unique.**

Granted this says *should*, so yes you can do it...but it may result in unpredictable behavior depending on who's parsing it down the road (*typically* the last property wins because of how most forward-reading parsers behave).

Also note that this RFC applies to JSON not object literals (JSON is a stricter subset of that), but the conventions apply to both.